# How to control scrolling speed using selenium Webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I used this but it scrolled the page very first

```
flag = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@src="newimg.png"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", flag)
```